# JavaScript OnBlur Event Blocking Click Event

Tags: javascript, onblur

I'm having a problem where an onblur event is blocking a click event. In my form a particular field will have the focus and I have an onblur event attached to it.  When the user clicks on the Save button, the onblur event fires but the click does not register on the button unless the user clicks it again.  My onblur is straight forward:

```
"onblur"="updateCategoryItem_exec(this)"
```

My updateCategoryItem_exec function is:

```
function updateCategoryItem_exec(element) {
    $.post(
        "/adex/mvc/editBudget/updateCategoryItem",
        {
            id: element.id,
            value: element.value
        },
        updateCategoryItem_complete,
        "text"
    );
}
```

I'm not sure why the click isn't firing because of the onblur.  Any ideas?

Comment: And what is the `onclick` event?

Comment: Is the button part of the DOM listening on `onblur`? This may be the case of event bubbling / trickling.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your question, PieOhPah, gave me an idea to try moving my Save button and that seems to have done the trick.  Not sure why, but it's working now.